# visually pretend a widget has focus without actually having it

Tags: qt

I need to paint a styled widget the same style as if it had a focus but without actually having the focus. My concrete case is a tool/popup list box (containing `QListView`) which should hover above other widgets but it **should not receive focus** (unlike `QCompleter` popup). But I would like to paint it the same style **as if it had focus**, i.e. blue highlighting of the current row instead of gray (in the default style in Windows 10). Can I somehow fake/pretend that a widget has a focus without actually having it, so that it can be painted as being focused?

I naively tried to call `qApp->postEvent(myPopup, new QFocusEvent(QEvent::FocusIn));` but it made no change and the popup still looks as if it has not focus.

I do not want to mess up my code with stylesheets or having to override the styled item delegate in some way as these feel like hack more than a clean code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement a proxy style that paints everything as if it was focused, and that's perhaps the only non-hacky, generic way that doesn't care about other details.